# Oncreate function is called once then why can the button work again and again?

Tags: java, android

This is the simple code I applied.Please explain why such behavior is taking place.Oncreate is not updating then why on click of button it can be called again and again

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    gaggan();
}

public void gaggan(){
    Button bt =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            EditText e2= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
            EditText e3= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
            int num1=Integer.parseInt(e2.getText().toString());
            int num2=Integer.parseInt(e3.getText().toString());
            int sum=num1+num2;
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,Integer.toString(sum), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging yet?

Comment: The code is correct sir.The app is working fine.

Comment: I wanted to know the reason for such behavior

Comment: Because once the memory is allocated when onCreate() is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bt.setOnClickListener` will register your click-listener (`new View.OnClickListener() {..}` on the button and thus, whenever the button is clicked, the `onClick()` method of your click-listener is executed.

The [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html) have a more detailed explanation

Comment: However Sir, If i do not put gaggan() in Oncreate method this does not happen Thats why I am confused

Comment: when you don't call `gaggan()` (whatever that means), then your click-listener is never registered.